# Is there a place to post texts for review?

Tags: discussion

Recently I started to learn French. To reinforce what I have learned so far and to improve my skills I have tried to write small texts, dialogs, and things like that, and I would like to get some feedback on them: Things such as choice of words, did I come up with sentences that a native (or experienced) speaker would use, and so on…

Is it fine to post such texts on `french.stackexchange.com`, or is there a better suited place for questions like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best *French Language Stack Exchange* has to offer for that is its [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette). You're welcome to say hello and post a link to your text. You'll likely find people happy to help you improve your text, discuss and maybe give you some tips. You may have to wait a bit cause people aren't online all the time.

Posting on the site itself is fine if you can identify a precise question you'd like to have an answer on. In this case provide all the context relevant to your question but don't make it too broad. You can of course ask several questions but in this case use a separate post for each of them.